# `could not call proc` error when running Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup

When I ran the following inno setup script, I got the following runtime error: could not call proc.

```
[Setup]
AppName=AppName
AppVersion=1.0
SetupIconFile=icon.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon=icon.ico
DefaultDirName=D:\test
OutputBaseFilename={#SetupSetting("AppName")}-{#SetupSetting("AppVersion")}

[Files]
Source: "Database\exec-mysql.cmd"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "Database\create-db.cmd"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "{code:GetDatabasePath}"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: external deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename:"exec-mysql.cmd"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}"; Description: "Create database"; StatusMsg: "Create database ..."; Flags:  runhidden waituntilterminated

[Code]
var
  SqlFilePage: TInputFileWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  SqlFilePage := CreateInputFilePage(wpSelectDir,
   'Select Database File Location',
   'Where is your Database file located ?',
   'Select where Database file is located, then click Next.');

  SqlFilePage.Add('Location of database file:',
   'Database files|*.sql|All files|*.*',
   '.sql');
end;

function GetDatabasePath(Param: string): string;
begin  
    Result := SqlFilePage.Values[0];  
end;
```

I need to get a file from user before execute the batch file

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? I'm not getting any error with your code. Can you post a log file?

Comment: I am getting the error in the following line:  Result := SqlFilePage.Values[0];

Comment: I cannot imagine why that line should be failing. Add some logging to your code and post the logs.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for my problem like this:

```
function GetDatabasePath(Param: string): string;
begin  
    if Assigned(SqlFilePage) then
      Result := SqlFilePage.Values[0]  
    else
      Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: But in your code, the `GetDatabasePath` is never called before the `SqlFilePage` is *assigned* – your code must be different than what you have posted.